Command '\ifstrequal' not evaluating to TRUE when arguments are indeed equal
I am trying to follow this post in defining a custom citation style where I show a different icon based on the type of the citation; as such, I am using the \ifstrequal command from the etoolbox package. However, in the example I provide, it evaluates the comparison {\printfield{entrytype}}{article} to FALSE, whilst if then ask LaTeX to actually display \printfield{entrytype}, it returns 'article', so this expression should be evaluated as TRUE. What is going wrong here; do I need to tell LaTeX to explicitly 'evaluate' {\printfield{entrytype}} before making the comparison (and if so, how)?
MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifstrequal{\printfield{entrytype}}{article}{\includegraphics[width=3mm]{example-image-a}}{\printfield{entrytype}}\printnames[family-given]{labelname}% <- This line gets evaluated to FALSE, but should be TRUE as the entrytype for 'sigfridsson' is 'article'
   \newunit%
   \printfield{journaltitle}%
   \newunit%
   \printlabeldateextra}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Here, I have some reference~\footcite{sigfridsson}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Result:


\printfield is a command to print something and that is clearly different to a string "article", even if it at the end prints article. biblatex knows lots of tests, so check its documentation and use those.

biblatex provides lots of suitable test commands. In your case you can use \ifentrytype:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifentrytype{article}{\includegraphics[width=3mm]{example-image-a}}{\printfield{entrytype}}\printnames[family-given]{labelname}% <- This line gets evaluated to FALSE, but should be TRUE as the entrytype for 'sigfridsson' is 'article'
   \newunit%
   \printfield{journaltitle}%
   \newunit%
   \printlabeldateextra}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Here, I have some reference~\footcite{sigfridsson}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


